# Removing NaN values and outliers from MATLAB data

Tags: matlab

I have some battery data, more specific sequence data of internal resistances of batteries. However, the data has measurement errors and also sometimes no values at all.
My current results are, that I am able to remove any NaNs from the data using [this package.](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint_nans?requestedDomain=)
Also I was able to solve the problems of outliers to some extent by utilizing MATLABs filloutliers function. Also I have tried to additionally add a moving averageHere is a sample code I have used:

```py
no_nans = results(52).internal_resistance_no_nans;

no_outliers = filloutliers(no_nans, 'linear','median');

with_mean = movmean(no_outliers,7);
```

Also here is the original data plotted:
[image: Figure containing the data]

My problem is that I am not satisfied with the current result. Especially because the spike at about index 32 is still too big in my opinion. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I am confused, the blue raw data looks like the best data to me? Can you just not interpolate the nans?

Comment: This is indeed confusing. Are the labels wrong in the plot? What's wrong with the data labeled "raw data"? Why does it need any processing at all?

Comment: FIRST : I agree with both Ander and Chris. The supplied graph shows no NaN. Could you supply raw samples graph with NaN? SECOND : In electronics while measuring R from V/I you have to be careful that those NaN mentioned in the question may not really be unknown, but open/short circuits. A battery itself does not generate NaN. It may be the acquisition module/function that rounds some values that then are erroneously brought to NaN when it should be an out of spects yet a real/complex impedance.

Comment: rewording : try to fix the NaN source. A NaN brought 'back' to an interpolated value may correspond to a battery cell that does not have the assumed value. Get NaN free measurements rather than drag them along data processing.

Comment: Hello! Thank you all for your answers! Of course you are right, I accidentally used an incorrect legend in the previous figure. I edited the question, so please have a look above.

Comment: Also thank you for your detailed comment @John BG but in my case the data is extracted from more complicated tests and these tests sometimes fail. If one test fails, the resistance can't be extracted at all from this test, and therefore the data sometimes has NaNs, just as a placeholder for a missing value.

Comment: As you can also see, I have added a moving average in the figure above, which makes the result better but also worse at the same time as it deforms the shape of the actual data.

Comment: `the spike at about index 32 is still too big in my opinion` - the problem you have is describing why that's your opinion _mathematically_. What's wrong with that point? Is it too far from the moving mean? In that case you can remove all points more than some distance from the movmean. Is it because it's the only value below 0.025? Similarly you could remove all of those. This is purely subjective unless you can characterise which points you want to remove, then it becomes a programming question if you're stuck on _how to implement that logic_.

Comment: Luca : Thanks for further comments and corrections on your question. I understand the problem because I worked in a production line where jigs and looms would occasionally 'fail' meaning the PCBs under test were neither pass or rejected with known problem. Say you go fishing : you keep trying until you get fish, or you don't get any at all. Anything else is irrelevant. A test that 'fails' to either OK or REJECT, or tell some values right on the line, is a test that has to ve improved.

Comment: if you test your car tyres pressure and the machine doesn't show psi, the display reads Merry Christmas, or shows 0psi yet you know there are 1.5atm at least, what do you do? you get another tester. Or do you keep trying on a tester that is not delivering??